# Как отображать картинку в pictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я видел то что написано на msdn, но после того как я указываю путь и запускаю программу, мне показывает только `ErrorImage`. Я уже даже провал с веб ссылки картинку, без толку, тот же результат. Мой код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\182.img"; 
}
```

Буду очень благодарен за ответ примером.

Comment: Это должно работать. Если показывает `ErrorImage`, очевидно, ошибка в пути к изображению.

Answer (score 1):

Если в одну строку, то вот так:

```
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Новая папка\182.img");
```

В целом, на MSDN отличный справочный материал - например, [про PictureBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx). Настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться справочными материалами - это гораздо быстрее.

Comment: Да, у меня получилось сделать вашим способом, видимо я слегка не там читал. Но все же хотелось бы узнать, можно ли как то сделать что бы не указывать полный путь к папке [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation(v=vs.110).aspx] в примере сказано что можно, но по нему у меня не отображает картинку, а когда я пытаюсь сделать `                  MyImage = new Bitmap(@"\WindowsFormsApplication18\WindowsFormsApplication18\Resources\76.png");` код не проходит, ошибка "не допустимый параметр"

Comment: Можно - например, если изображение лежит в папке со скомпилированной программой. Тогда достаточно указать имя файла. В случае, если вы запускаете своё приложение из Visual Studio, скомпилированное приложение лежит примерно здесь: `{путь к проекту}/bin/Debug` или `{путь к проекту}/bin/Release`